# Laravel app that is hosted on IIS windows 10 and that how can I access on another PC?

Tags: laravel, iis, xampp

I have hosted laravel app on IIS windows 10, that app running on local and I wanted to access on another PC over the internet/intranet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to configure your iis to allow incoming connections. check this post [link to post](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2886/How-to-configure-IIS-to-access-website-using-IP-address.html)

Comment: this is working only on the same local internet, I wanted to access over the internet, is this possible?